# Buffer to linestring in shapely produces extra line

Tags: python, shapely

Here is my code:

```py
from shapely import wkt

line_string = 'LINESTRING(114.337434257064 22.6869985219834,114.3375897 22.6869952,114.3378091 22.6869939,114.3379256 22.6869866,114.338153 22.6869723,114.3383013 22.6869747,114.3384207 22.6869932,114.3386951 22.6870794,114.3388456 22.6871314,114.3397001 22.6874642,114.340615 22.6878098,114.3406906 22.68785,114.3407353 22.6878952,114.3407928 22.6879718,114.34084529879 22.6881214965493,114.34084529879 22.6881214965493,114.3408453 22.6881215)'
line_string = wkt.loads(line_string)

polygon = line_string.buffer(0.00020, cap_style=2, join_style=2).wkt

print(polygon)
```

And I get the output as:

```py
POLYGON ((114.3375924292975 22.68719518733905, 114.3378159518402 22.68719386291196, 114.3379381076579 22.68718620851308, 114.3381576652242 22.68717240168781, 114.338284290118 22.68717445091064, 114.338375160633 22.68718853051304, 114.3386324603347 22.68726935862634, 114.338776625568 22.68731916986973, 114.3396284692013 22.68765093530119, 114.340532377289 22.68799238314804, 114.3405698099089 22.68801228779516, 114.340583522319 22.68802615358793, 114.3406142971512 22.68806715101655, 114.340656568431 22.68818768455116, 114.340656566767 22.68818767980638, 114.341034033233 22.68805532019362, 114.341034032023 22.68805531674292, 114.3409713028488 22.68787644898345, 114.340887077681 22.68776424641207, 114.3408113900911 22.68768771220484, 114.340697622711 22.68762721685196, 114.3397717307987 22.68727746469881, 114.338914574432 22.68694363013026, 114.3387577396653 22.68688944137366, 114.338466239367 22.68679786948696, 114.338318309882 22.68677494908936, 114.3381483347758 22.68677219831219, 114.3379130700871 22.68678699288144, 114.3378022481598 22.68679393708804, 114.3375869707025 22.68679521266094, 114.3374299838238 22.68679856764007, 114.3374385303043 22.68719847632673, 114.3375924292975 22.68719518733905))
```

I figure this polygon in QGIS and find a problem: the right top corner of the figure has one line across the border as the image show:

[total polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HatWo.png)

[right top corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFJet.png)

**note:you have to zoom in many times to see the extra line, I recommend you to check whether `Point(114.340656568431 22.68818768455116)` is in the polygon printed.**

And I find the coordinates of that extra point is `114.340656568431 22.68818768455116`, I want to know why the extra line generates and how to avoid it.

I also make some tests via changing the first parameter in buffer() corresponding to length, then I find that while length ≤ 0.00016 there won't be extra line, but as length ≥ 0.00017 the extra line appears.

**Steps to reproduce the problem.**

Just run the code above

**Operating system**

Windows 10, Python 3.9

**Shapely version and provenance**

1.7.1 installed from PyPI using pip

Comment: When you `print(polygon.is_valid)`, what does it output? What happens when you apply a zero-buffer as `polygon.buffer(0)`?

Comment: It feels like a bug in the buffer algorithm, perhaps in the part that makes the end caps flat. Report that for the shapely project.

Comment: This dangle also appears in QGIS, when I use a buffer for `'LINESTRING(114.337434257064 22.6869985219834,114.3375897 22.6869952,114.3378091 22.6869939,114.3379256 22.6869866,114.338153 22.6869723,114.3383013 22.6869747,114.3384207 22.6869932,114.3386951 22.6870794,114.3388456 22.6871314,114.3397001 22.6874642,114.340615 22.6878098,114.3406906 22.68785,114.3407353 22.6878952,114.3407928 22.6879718,114.34084529879 22.6881214965493,114.34084529879 22.6881214965493,114.3408453 22.6881215)'`

Comment: What is the shapely version because i have no errors with the 1.7.1